# Problem with interrogation my API with mongoose

Tags: express, mongoose

I have a problem with the result of my query at the database mongoDB.
When I exec my query the result is always empty: [].
I'm new user, please help me.
I use SO Mac OS Catalina.
This code is in the access of my API (I obscured my password)

```
//connection on mongoDB
let URI =
  "mongodb+srv://marco:<xxxxxxxxx>@persona-iydyz.gcp.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
mongoose.connect(URI, 
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

  mongoose.connection.on('connected', () => {console.log('mongodb connected')})
```

and this code is in my route who exec the query

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const persona = require('./../classes/persona')

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    let result = persona.find().exec();
    res.send(result);
});

module.exports = router;
```

I don't understand why my result is always empty.
please help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any mongoose model method should be called with a callback, otherwise it just builds a query, not executes it. exec() is there to execute this built query. You can use callback directly if you do not have to do something with built query.

Then try with the below code:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   persona.find({}, (err, result) => {
      if(err) 
        return res.send(err.message);
      return res.send(result)
   })
});
```

If you are using promisified mongoose, then it will be

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   try {
     let result = await persona.find({});
     return res.send(result);
   } catch(err) {
     return res.send(err.message);
   }
});
```

P.S. Check is the mongoDb is connected successfully or not!